# rake db:create showing error on rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to connect to mysql and using command rake db:create
. It is showing me error

```
rake aborted! No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb) /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also tried rake db:migrate as well but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your missing a rake file. Add this code in a file called Rakefile at the root of your app. 
Edit: Replace YourApp by the name of your app

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

YourApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: require_relative 'config/application'

Myrail::Application.load_tasks

Comment: Don't know how to build task 'db:create' (see --tasks)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)